# ESLint: Cannot find module 'lib/rules/max-classes-per-file.js'

Tags: javascript, node-modules, eslint

I need your help. I've installed **eslint npm package** (4.19.1) to use Airbnb style guide and make good practices.

So, I've configured the options for my rules and then when I write my code, the message says the following:

`ESLint: Cannot find module '/X/Y/Desktop/project/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/max-classes-per-file.js'. Please see the 'ESLint' output channel for details.`

I look in node_modules and this wasn't here.

**How can I resolve that problem?**
Thanks in advance.

Greetings, 
Fran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-classes-per-file#version

> This rule was introduced in ESLint 5.0.0-alpha.3.

Remove `max-classes-per-file` rule from `.eslintrc` or use ESLint v.5.x.x

if You've installed eslint globally just call following to download latest package (v.5.1.0 now):

```
sudo npm i -g eslint
```

Comment: That's right num8er! Thank you for your help. I've unistalled 4.19 version and I've installed the last version. With that, the problem disappears.